# SignalR in Synology NAS in deployed with VS Studio and Docker Hub

Tags: asp.net, docker, signalr

I deployed an ASP.NET Web API application in VS Studio to Docker hub and run it on a Synology NAS. So the normal endpoints work fine, but I use a SignalR connection to my Blazor Wasm clients. This connection is not working anymore, but I don't know why...

I use the synologie.me domain with LetsEncrypt certificate. In the reverse proxy settings in my DS I also declared the websocket headers:

```
Upgrade --> $http_upgrade
Connection --> $connection_upgrade
```

The error in Developer Tools is:

[image]

It is at the point where I want to start the hubconnection in my code.

Does anyone know what I have to change too?

Regards Samuel

Comment: Elaborate on "connection is not working anymore", I assume you are using Developer Tools in your browser, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: Hello, see the new image in the MainQuestion with the error